# 1990 Fox body mustang

Tags: ignition, starter

My cars battery is charged and the lights turn on and the door locks work BUT when I turn the key the dash dosnt light up and the gauges don’t move at all and the car dosnt start. No sound as if the starter is trying to turn the car over just NOTHING. I’m 16 just trying to get this car running anyone have a solution?

Comment: Check your fuses first.

Comment: What else works?  Horn, wipers, stereo?

Answer (score 0):

I found these wiring diagrams [here](http://www.veryuseful.com/mustang/tech/engine/#Diagrams), hopefully they are for your car.

The relay marked EEC power relay could cause this issue (top middle of first diagram and bottom right of second diagram).  Try to find its location and check if it clicks when the ignition is turned on.
A faulty ignition switch could also cause the issue, since it supplies power to the relay.
The top diagram also shows a safety switch for both manual and automatic transmissions, it would be worth checking that out too.

[image]

[image]